# What technique can be used to access DOM element(get and set value) placed under *ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to access `<span>`, `<select>` element. My code template is like below

```
<div *ngFor="---">
  <div>
    <span></span>
    <select>
     <option></option>
     <option></option>
     <option></option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following technique in angular 2+.
Trying to fetch Select for example:

```
<div #wrapper> 
    <div *ngFor="---; i = index">
      <div>
        <span></span>
        <select [(ngModule)]="'selectElement' + i">
         <option></option>
         <option></option>
         <option></option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And in the same component .ts file:

```
 @ViewChildren('wrapper') wrapper: QueryList<any>;
```

and then all you need to do to use it is:

```
this.wrapper
```

or by using all the various selectElement# referring the index in the ngFor

Comment: So as it is a ngFor loop you may have several `selectElement1`

Comment: does this help?

Comment: For a more generic method, see `@ViewChildren()` (note the plural form).

Answer (score 3):

Use `QueryList` & `ViewChildren` to get elements in `*ngFor`;

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.sp1)
  }

  @ViewChildren('swrapper') sp1: QueryList<any>;
```

HTML:

```
<div #wrapper> 
    <div *ngFor="---; i = index">
      <div>
        <span></span>
        <select [(ngModule)]="'selectElement' + i">
         <option></option>
         <option></option>
         <option></option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```